# Show a badge notification with Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am creating a chat app with Firestore. I saw a lot of information about creating a badge notification with cloud messaging but not a lot of information with creating a badge notification without cloud message. Does anyone know how to do this? I am trying to show a dot on an icon when a user receives a message that they have not read. It would be even better if I could could the total number of messages that they have not read too.

**Firestore Structure**

```
 users
      |
      ---- chatList (subcollection)
              ---- chatFrom: user1_Id
              ---- chatWith: user2_Id
              ---- chatRoomId: smallerUserID_biggerUserID
chatRooms
      |
      ---- smallerUserID_biggerUserID (subcollection)
              ---- content: "Hello"
              ---- id: 1613422354427
              ---- idFrom: user1_Id
              ---- timestamp: 1613422354427
```

**Getting and Sending a messages in chatRooms Collection**

```
getMessages() {
  this.listMessage = []; 
  
  db.collection('chatRooms').doc(this.chatRoomId).collection(this.chatRoomId)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          this.listMessage.push(change.doc.data());
        }
     });
  });
},

async sendMessage(content) {
  if (content.trim() === '') { return }
  
  const timestamp = moment().valueOf().toString();
  const idFrom = this.authUser.userId;
  const idTo = this.currentPeerUser.userId;
  const message = { id: timestamp, idFrom, idTo, timestamp, content };

  const chatRoomRef = db.collection('chatRooms').doc(this.chatRoomId)
                        .collection(this.chatRoomId).doc(timestamp);
  await chatRoomRef.set(message);

  this.inputValue = '';
},
```

Comment: I think you need an additional property on the message, stating whether or not the message was read by the recipient. It is up to the front-end to determine when it was read or not.

Comment: I figured that I need that but I haven't decided how to determine if someone reads a message or not. The biggest issue I was having is when someone is in the chatRoom and a new message was sent. I'm not sure how to tell if that message was read. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You could use something called [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to determine whether or not the message has come into the viewport of the recipient, and then update the message in Firestore, flagged as e.g. `readByUsers:[user1]`? Or something similar

Comment: @Alex can you share the code you have already for showing new messages?

Comment: @John that’s sounds pretty cool. I’m going to look into the Intersection Observer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Rafael sure will. I’ll edit my post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @John, a better option would be to have an extra field in your objects that tells if the message has been read or not and it can be done with some simple changes like this to you `getMessages()`:

```
getMessages() {
  this.listMessage = []; 
  
  db.collection('chatRooms').doc(this.chatRoomId).collection(this.chatRoomId)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          this.listMessage.push({
              isNew: true,
              message: change.doc.data()
          });
        }
     });
  });
}
```

You can use isNew to show or not show a newMessage icon and to change it's value when the message is read you can use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) by adding the following to your code:

```
//options to your observer
let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#YOUR_ROOT_ELEMENT_HERE'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

let target = document.querySelector('#YOUR_TARGET_ELEMENT_HERE');
observer.observe(target);

let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    this.listMessage.forEach(function(messageItem) {
        messageItem.isNew = false;
    });
};
```

In this example `YOUR_ROOT_ELEMENT_HERE` will be the parent of your element, I assume in this case it could be a Scroll and `YOUR_TARGET_ELEMENT_HERE` will be the unread message. When the intersection happened all messages will be marked as read, but you can refine that logic as you see fit.